# Clone a void refund transaction record to cancel each other out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
Account_ID   Amount
123          200
```

Result

```
Account_ID   Amount
123          200
123          -200
```

Typically, our database will have two transactions for a void refund payment, but somehow few records only have one transaction.

I know I can manually insert a same record into the table.
Is there any other ways to clone a record and set the amount to negative without using insert statment?

Comment: well if you want another record in your database (whether cloned or not) you will need to INSERT a record. Rows cant just appear from nowhere :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though as M.Ali said it is not good to clone record but we can achieve but i didn't exactly know if it suits your requirement or not

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
    ([Account_ID] int, [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO @T
    ([Account_ID], [Amount])
VALUES
    (123, 200)
;

;WITH CTE AS (select Account_ID,Amount,row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Amount ORDER BY (Select NULL))RN from @T
CROSS APPLY(values('Account_ID',Account_ID),('Amount',Amount))M(v,s))
Select Account_ID,
CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN cast(Amount as varchar) ELSE 
'-' + cast(Amount as varchar)END
from CTE
```